# Cache home page for non-authenticated users in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, outputcache

My website have a home page, and I would like to cache that page for anonymous users, and set it as "private" for authenticated users (so they save it on their computers, nowhere else).

So, if the user is anonymous I want to save the page in the server cache, and also in the browser cache using `Cache-control:public, max-age=60` and `Vary:Cookie`, so if the browser gets authenticated and send a cookie, the browser won't reuse the former stored page.

If the user is authenticated, then I do not want the page be stored in the server, but I do on the customer browser  using `Cache-control:private, max-age=60`.

I have been trying with several combinations with OutputCacheAttribute and Response.Cache but I cannot get it right.

What would be the best way of doing it?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You may try implementing a `VaryByCustom` rule that will distinguish between anonymous and authenticated users. Here's [an example](http://visitmix.com/writings/using-varybycustom-with-outputcache-in-asp-net-mvc-to-support-caching-for-logged-in-users) that should put you on the right track.

Comment: Hi. That is what I tried first but it didn't work. Now I am trying to figure out why it is not working, take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210581/outputcache-is-sending-wrong-vary-header-when-the-call-hits-the-cache. Cheers.

Comment: In your link is just using the server side caching, I am interested in  HTTP caching on the client and downstream as well.

Comment: You can specify proxy/client-level caching like so:      context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);